# Simple way to get x-coordinate of already drawn SVG Path

Tags: svg, svg-path

I have an already drawn SVG as shown below. It has a set of vertical paths. 
 [image]

 Is there any simple way to get the x coordinates of each of them?

Comment: Use the SVG DOM: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#DOMInterfaces

Comment: var paths = document.getElementsByTagName('path');
alert(paths[0].getAttribute("d"));
I was able to get the "d" attribute values with the above code like this. 
"M56 50 L 1188 50 1188 460 56 460Z". Did you mean a this kind of way? Still searching for getting the exact path i want.

Comment: Sorry, Got it. Now I'm looking on svg DOM. Thanks. Is it also possible to do the same thing with the way I mentioned above since I only want to do it for a SVGs with the exact same structure?

Comment: Sure it's possible or I wouldn't have suggested it ;-)